# AttributeError when trying to install using pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm running Python 2.7.9 on Yosemite (10.10.2), and my pip installation has gone wrong.
I can no longer install pip using `get-pip.py`:

```
sth:~ $ sudo python get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20204, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 152, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 130, in bootstrap
    sys.exit(pip.main(["install", "--upgrade"] + packages + args))
  File "/tmp/tmpdUeSSr/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main

  File "/tmp/tmpdUeSSr/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 183, in main
  File "/tmp/tmpdUeSSr/pip.zip/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
  File "/tmp/tmpdUeSSr/pip.zip/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```

I can use `easy_install`, and then create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin`, but trying to install using it gives me the same error, subsequently:

```
sth:~ $ sudo pip install twine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.0.8', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 183, in main
    for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
    del logging._handlerList[:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```

I'm certain it's not a problem with pip, so wondering what I've done wrong…

Comment: It appears that for some reason your `logging` module is outdated. Check your version by `import logging; print 
logging.__version__`. If it is outdated run `easy_install logging`.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for necroing but for the sake of other googlers:

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3193), you should *not* install `logging` with `pip` as it messes up the system version. I am not sure when this changed though.

So removing `yourpythoninstallpath/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logging` should remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd gotten a similar error an hour ago and found this question.
However I've solved it just now.
Although you might not think it useful, I hope this answer helps you solving the problem.

In fact, when I use *virtualenvwrapper*, I want to control an ENV suddenly.
So I created a backup directory for the reason **in the same directory where another ENV is.**

After that, There were not only 2 ENVs but also 3 directories related to ENV in *.virtualenv*. 
It made some path to site-packages and etc change helter-skelter apparently.

That is why, if you don't confirm the files about *Virtualenv*, I reccomend you to do.

The error with me is the following.

```
    ~  pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 183, in main
    for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
    del logging._handlerList[:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```