# pip failing with attribute error: no attribute _handerList

Tags: python, pip

I just installed "logging" from pip and now pip is broken. I've tried `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip*; sudo easy_install pip` and it didn't resolve the issue. The full result from attempting to install a package:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 179, in main
    for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
    del logging._handlerList[:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError when trying to install using pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365790/attributeerror-when-trying-to-install-using-pip)

Comment: I seems this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365790/attributeerror-when-trying-to-install-using-pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attempt to properly reinstall `pip` either via Python itself or using `easy_install` with upgrade enforced.

**Python**

`python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip`

**easy_install**

`sudo easy_install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Easy install worked. Python was still causing error. Thanks